# Why can not get the override width and height in the container of Sprite extended object?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, overriding

I have a object called Square that extends Sprite:

```
package {

    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.geom.Point;

    public class Square extends Sprite {

        private var _point:Point = new Point(100, 100);

        public function Square() {
            // empty object
        }

        override public function set height(n:Number):void {
            _point.y = n;
        }

        override public function set width(n:Number):void {
            _point.x = n;
        }

        override public function get height():Number {
            return _point.y;
        }

        override public function get width():Number {
            return _point.x;
        }

    }
}
```

And in my Main document class, I've tried access width and height of square container, like this:

```
import flash.display.Sprite;

var container:Sprite = new Sprite();
var square:Square = new Square();

container.addChild(square);

trace(square.width, square.height); // 100 100
trace(container.width, container.height); // 0 0
```

I know my Square object is empty, but I override the width and height methods. I got it in the first trace, but not in the second, should it not work?

Comment: A potential typecast to `Sprite` within `Sprite::width` and `Sprite::height` can be the reason of your overrides not affect the calculation of container's width and height. Unconfirmed ofc :)

Comment: What is your expected result? In `Square` you override the _truthful_ values  of width/height, if queried, with those _imaginary_ ones (taken from a Point) but you haven't really changed any size (your "empty object" has no size)... So you make a new `Container` (also has zero size) and add zero sized `Square` as child. Total size=zero. You can try (untested) as `override public function get height():String` which returns as `var _string:String="hello"; return _string;` now if you check using `trace(square.height);` should result in `hello`. How could it increase `Container` size? It won't

Comment: PS: A `Point` is just for noting some position / coordinates etc.. Try making a `Shape` (or any visual content) in the `Square` class to affect reported size dimensions. What do you want to achieve by overriding? Maybe there is a solution if you explain

Comment: @Vesper, it seems so... It seems to be something beyond a simple override of the function.

Comment: @VC.One, I thought that override the width and height was enough... But not...

Comment: Guys, Sorry... My english it's not good... I edited the title of my question, is it good?

Comment: @biio about overriding.. well _**Flash Player***_ will still know that you have an empty object and it cannot claim it has any size. If it really worked like your code setup, people would complain of either a "bug" or "vulnerability" (though I wonder if other languages like Java or C# allow it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overriding width and height DOES work and you can see that in:

`trace(square.width, square.height); // 100 100`

But I'm afraid it's not gonna work as you want it to in this example.
Why `trace(container.width, container.height);` is giving you 0, 0 then?
While the actual implementation it's not available I'm pretty sure it's not as simple as getting width and height of all children. If it was, what if you have 2 elements next to each other? Would the output be 200, 100 ? 100, 200?
What if elements overlap each other (fully or partially only)?

So instead of simply getting dimensions of the children flash is figuring it out by doing some other magic (sorry no idea how it is implemented) it is actually checking what's there. And as you said, your square object is empty, so that' why you're getting 0, 0.

Comment: Thanks, but as you explained, i can't do that. I solved this using the `square.graphics.drawRect(0,0, _point.x, _point.y)`... I draw a 'invisible rectangle' into object and now `container.width` and `container.height` are working and showing 100 100.

Comment: @VC.One, yep, but I still think this is a quick fix (or 'gambiarra' in Portuguese, a thing not good to program). But worked... I'll do with this for now... The inconvenient is `clear()` the graphics in some parts of my project everytime I do this...

Comment: @biio Instead of overriding why not just set `square.width = square.height = 100;` after `var square:Square = new Square();` ...not tested so either it'll work or still says container size is zero. But yes, you cannot measure pixel width of an empty class without any displayable thing(s) inside it to provide such pixel size data.